# Create query that contains movements out of destination list

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given is a table of containers and their current location:

```
Date         Container    Location    Scrapped
---------------------------------------------
2015/08/25   Container1   A
2015/08/25   Container2   B
2015/08/25   Container3   C
2015/08/26   Container1   D
2015/08/26   Container2   A
2015/08/26   Container3   B
2015/08/27   Container1   D              x
2015/08/27   Container4   B
2015/08/27   Container2   C
2015/08/27   Container3   A
```

What I need is a list of movements from a given date. So lets take the `2015/08/26` as the desired date, the output should be as follow:

```
Date         Container    From   To   Scrapped
----------------------------------------------
2015/08/26   Container1   A      D
2015/08/26   Container2   B      A
2015/08/26   Container3   C      B
2015/08/27   Container1   D      D       x
2015/08/27   Container4   null   B
2015/08/27   Container2   A      C
2015/08/27   Container3   B      A
```

Creating a query that gives me by the enpoints is quite easy:

```
select
    Date,
    Container,
    Location as [To],
    Scrapped
from
    ContainerMovements
where
    Date >= '2015/08/26'
```

But how can i fill up the From column by accessing the corresponding row from the older date? I'm quite sure it must be some kind of left (or if you take the column order a right) join, due to the fact that new containers can come up and the From column could be null, but I'm currently simply stucked on that.

The table resides within a SQL Server 2008 R2.

To make it easier [here everything is pre-defined at SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfa82/1/0).

Comment: You might have to use self join. But Can you create some sample fiddle ?? So that it could be easy to answer you.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana: Okay, takes some minutes, but I'll do so.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana: SQLfiddle is up and waiting. ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one gives your expected results. [Demo fiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65f8d/37).

```
DECLARE @date DATE = '20150826'

SELECT t1.[Date], t1.Container, 
       (SELECT TOP(1) t2.Location 
               FROM Table1 t2
               WHERE t2.Container = t1.Container AND t2.[date] < t1.[date]
               ORDER BY t2.[Date] DESC ) [from], 
        t1.Location [To], t1.Scrapped
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.[Date] >= @date
ORDER BY t1.[Date]
```

Output:

```
|                     Date |  Container |   from | To | Scrapped |
|--------------------------|------------|--------|----|----------|
| August, 26 2015 00:00:00 | Container1 |      A |  D |   (null) |
| August, 26 2015 00:00:00 | Container2 |      B |  A |   (null) |
| August, 26 2015 00:00:00 | Container3 |      C |  B |   (null) |
| August, 27 2015 00:00:00 | Container1 |      D |  D |        x |
| August, 27 2015 00:00:00 | Container4 | (null) |  B |   (null) |
| August, 27 2015 00:00:00 | Container2 |      A |  C |   (null) |
| August, 27 2015 00:00:00 | Container3 |      B |  A |   (null) |
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `self join` like below should do it:

```
SELECT [Current].[Date], 
Prev.Container, 
Prev.Location [FROM], 
[Current].Location [TO], 
[Current].Scrapped

FROM

(
 SELECT [Date], 
 Container, 
 Location, 
 Scrapped, 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Container ORDER BY [Date]) rown
FROM dbo.ContainerMovements
) Prev

JOIN

(
 SELECT [Date], 
 Container, 
 Location, 
 Scrapped, 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Container ORDER BY [Date]) rown
FROM dbo.ContainerMovements
) [Current]

on Prev.Container = [Current].Container 
AND Prev.rown + 1 = [Current].rown 
AND [Current].[Date] = '2015/08/26'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and here is the [**SQL fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfa82/28)

```
SELECT [Date]
    ,[Container]
    ,[From]
    ,[To]
    ,Scrapped
FROM (
    SELECT ct.DATE
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY ct.Container
            ,ct.DATE ORDER BY frm.DATE DESC
            ) AS row_num
        ,ct.Container
        ,frm.Location AS [FROM]
        ,ct.Location AS [To]
        ,Scrapped = CASE 
            WHEN ct.Scrapped = 0
                THEN ''
            ELSE 'x'
            END
    FROM ContainerMovements ct
    LEFT JOIN ContainerMovements frm ON ct.Container = frm.Container
        AND frm.[Date] < ct.[Date]
    WHERE ct.DATE >= '2015/08/26'
    ) tbl
WHERE tbl.row_num = 1
ORDER BY tbl.DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version with `FULL JOIN`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(d DATE, c VARCHAR(20), l CHAR(1))
DECLARE @d DATE = '2015/08/26'

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('2015/08/25',   'Container1',   'A'),
('2015/08/25',   'Container2',   'B'),
('2015/08/25',   'Container3',   'C'),
('2015/08/26',   'Container1',   'D'),
('2015/08/26',   'Container2',   'A'),
('2015/08/26',   'Container3',   'B'),
('2015/08/27',   'Container1',   'D'),
('2015/08/27',   'Container4',   'B'),
('2015/08/27',   'Container2',   'C'),
('2015/08/27',   'Container3',   'A')

SELECT tn.d, tn.c, tp.l f, tn.l t, CASE WHEN tp.l = tn.l THEN 'x' END s
FROM @t tn
FULL JOIN @t tp ON tn.c = tp.c AND tn.d = DATEADD(dd, 1, tp.d)
WHERE tn.d IN(@d, DATEADD(dd, 1, @d))
```

Output:

```
d           c           f    t  s
2015-08-26  Container1  A    D  NULL
2015-08-26  Container2  B    A  NULL
2015-08-26  Container3  C    B  NULL
2015-08-27  Container1  D    D  x
2015-08-27  Container4  NULL B  NULL
2015-08-27  Container2  A    C  NULL
2015-08-27  Container3  B    A  NULL
```